# What is file expansion?

Tags: linux, windows, path, operating-system, filepath

found this and could understand

Example: Windows 8.3 filename expansion “c:\program files” be -
comes “C:\PROGRA~1”

i tryed to navigate to the two paths and they worked both

anyone could make it clear

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename

Answer (score 1):

This is a holdover from the days of Windows 95, which revamped the filesystem FAT to FAT32, which enabled long filenames, and was a part of the selling point of the system itself.

At the time, there was still, old DOS packages, old Win 3.1 packages, that relied on the old filename convention 8.3 that is, 8 characters with 3 character for extension.

Windows 95 incorporated the API, to convert automatically in both directions, whilst maintaining compatibility with the existing FAT system, even after using the convert FAT utility. This was to ensure that no breakage of the files occurred, in the context of the old applications on it.

That API is still available to this day.

- `GetShortPathName` with the long filename as parameter, returns the short 8.3, with abbreviation in the form of `~`.
- `GetLongPathName` with the 8.3 filename as parameter, returns the long filename.

Source found in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In ye olde days, the FAT file system used by MS-DOG only supported eight character file names.

When MS switched to the FAT32 file system that used longer names (and later to the NTFS, this created migration issues. There were old systems that only supported 8+3 file names that would be accessing FAT32 disks over a network and there would be old software that only worked with 8+3 file names.

The solution MS came up with was to create short path names that used ~ and numbers to create unique 8+3 aliases for longer file names.

If you were on an old system and accessing a networked disk (or even using DOS commands on a FAT32 local disk early on):

c:\program files

became

C:\PROGRA~1

If you had

c:\program settings

That might come out as

C:\PROGRA~2

In short, this was then a system for creating unique 8+3 file names that mapped to longer file names so that they could be used with legacy systems and software.